# Re-importing a WSDL to update Java web service client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans, wsdl

I am developing a java program which calls a web service.  I am using NetBeans as my development environment.  I imported the WSDL and Netbeans created the classes I needed.  I have been happily coding for several weeks.  The owner of the web service has released two updates since then.  With the second update, I started getting errors from the web service.  The obvious first step is to update my program.

Here is my question, I have the WSDL URL for the udpate.  How do I "re-import" and update all my existing classes?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How did net beans created the classes at first palce ?

Comment: It uses its own interface to, what I assume it, wsimport.  you provide the URL of the WDSL and it creates all the classes.

Answer (score 1):

I finally came across the solution.  In the project view, you can right-click on the specific web service connection and click either "Refresh" which will re-read the WSDL if you are calling the same URL,  or you can delete the connection and readd it using the new URL.